# google-app-engine deploy error

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

2010-04-20 15:33:39,421 WARNING appengine_rpc.py:399 ssl module not found.
Without the ssl module, the identity of the remote host cannot be verified, and
connections may NOT be secure. To fix this, please install the ssl module from
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssl .
To learn more, see http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#rpcssl .

how can i do  ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the message describes, install the SSL module from that URL. Or, if you're not concerned about using a secure connection to authenticate and upload your app, just ignore the message.